# How to load Iframe content so that it does not flicker

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iframe, flicker

I have kept Iframe inside updtae panel but then also it flickers every time it reload. I think I can use javascript to load my content of Iframe in order to make it flicker free.Is this way correct? If yes, then How can I do it? And if not, then What should I do?

This is the code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="width:100%; height: 195px; margin-left: -7px;">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderChatRequest" runat="server">
                <iframe id="iframe1" frameborder="0" style=" width: 379px;
                        height:110%;" src="frmChatRequest.aspx"
                        scrolling="no" runat="server">
                </iframe>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```